# When I build a widget from a firebase firestore stream, every time the widget its build is counts as a read for firebase billing?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I build a widget from a firebase firestore stream, every time the widget is build it count as a read for firebase billing ?

Comment: Yes. It counts. I can confirm on usage statistics on firebase panel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because if you use transaction, it consider it as new reads, therefore the updated data from same document or collection will be updated in the UI also.

I prefere to read it one time and store it in List od object or as Stream, then use it whenever and where I want.